# How to operationalize stratified, cluster survey sample “standard of the mean” in Excel

Tags: sas, excel, survey-sampling, clustered-standard-errors, taylor-series

I have a question on the analysis of complex survey design. Basically, I am trying to replicate the **SAS** **Surveymeans** procedure in Excel in order to understand how to operationalize the equations to compute the **Standard Error of the Mean**.

I know this is a complicated process and can typically be conducted with various statistical software– but I need to understand the step-by-step equation calculations so that I can program them into a visual analytics platform. I was able to work out the equations to calculate the standard error of the sum – but I am stuck on the standard error of the means calculation.

I have gone through the SAS Surveymeans documentation (https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/stat/142/surveymeans.pdf) closely, but could not figure out how to calculate the standard error of the mean using the **Taylor Series Linearization** method.

I am attaching the link to the dataset here- https://github.com/tastaba/Standard-Error-Computations if anyone is interested to play around with it.

An example of dummy dataset is given below. The dataset consists of **3 strata** and **10 PSU/clusters**. **UtilityWt** variable is used to calculate the statistical inference here-

### Dataset

[image]

The calculations for standard error of sum in excel and corresponding SAS output is shown below-

### Standard Error of Sum in Excel- Computed

[image]

Here’s an output of SAS Surveymeans with a highlight of what I am hoping to calculate in Excel-

### Standard Error of Mean Output in SAS- want to compute in Excel

[image]

I have tried to follow Lumley's "**Survey Analysis in R**" documentation and Lohr's "**Sampling: Design and Analysis**" and haven't been able to figure out the math behind the calculations. I would also like to know whether there is a way to translate between an estimate of the mean (and standard error) and an estimate of the total (and standard error) or are they fundamentally different calculations? (This question was also asked in this post- [Transforming between estimates of mean and total (complex survey design)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444644/transforming-between-estimates-of-mean-and-total-complex-survey-design), but the answer is not quite what I am looking for.)

I would really appreciate any insights/help regarding this.
Have a great day! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation will depend on the survey design: there's not a single formula that can be used for every design.

However, there is a very commonly-used approximation in the case that you can assume that your PSUs were selected as simple random samples within the strata. This approximation is what is used by SAS or the R survey package if all you specify are weights and IDs for strata and PSUs/clusters.

The SAS documentation for PROC SURVEYMEANS describes this approximation's formulas [here](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_surveymeans_details06.htm&locale=en). I've copied below some screenshots of the relevant part of this documentation. Note that while this is from SAS documentation, the R survey package uses equivalent calculations.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The only notation not explained above is `f_h`, which is the number of PSUs sampled in stratum `h` divided by the number of PSUs which exist in stratum `h`. Often it is just assumed that `f_h` is a small number and so it set to zero.